# Pine Script = Line between divergence point

Tags: tradingview-api

I want to code a line that connects 2 divergences points and repaint as the Stochastic evolve, but I can seem to get it right. If possible I'd like the line to delete once a new divergence is detected.
Here is the divergence code.

```
Lenght_Div2 = input.int(650, "Moyenne", step = 10, group ="Divergence Stochastic")
LUP_2 = fixnan(ta.lowest(k15, Lenght_Div2)[1])
LP_2 = fixnan(ta.lowest(low, Lenght_Div2)[1])

div_Pos2 = k15 > LUP_2[1] and low < LP_2[1]
hdiv_Pos2 = k15 < LUP_2[1] and low > LP_2[1]

//

HUP_2 = fixnan(ta.highest(k15, Lenght_Div2)[1])
HP_2 = fixnan(ta.highest(high, Lenght_Div2)[1])

hdiv_Neg2 = k15 > HUP_2[1] and high < HP_2[1]
div_Neg2 = k15 < HUP_2[1] and high > HP_2[1]

plotshape(div_Pos2 ? -53 : na, location = location.absolute, color = color.rgb(0, 255, 34), style = shape.labelup, size = size.small)
plotshape(hdiv_Pos2 ? -53 : na, location = location.absolute, color = color.rgb(0, 8, 255), style = shape.labelup, size = size.small)
plotshape(div_Neg2 ? 53 : na, location = location.absolute, color = color.rgb(255, 0, 0), style = shape.labeldown, size = size.small)
plotshape(hdiv_Neg2 ? 53 : na, location = location.absolute, color = color.rgb(255, 149, 0), style = shape.labeldown, size = size.small)

//line.new(x1 = bar_index[1], y1 = LUP_2[0], x2 = bar_index, y2 = k15, color = color.rgb(255, 255, 255), style = line.style_solid, width = 1)
```

I don't know how to properly use de line.new fonction, make a ton of research but, I failed to get it right.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please edit your question and paste the entire code so that we can test it. Also can you provide a chart or an image to illustrate what you are looking for ?